# Visual studio 2022, Press '(' on selected text not working (as expected)

Tags: autocomplete, selection, matching, visual-studio-2022

I don't know how to describe this behaivor:

Press `(` key on selected text in vs2022, what i want is to replace the whole selection with `(`, but it does not, even worse, what it does is to add another `)` to the end of the selection, this is really annoying and happened many times. i tried to find options in Tools/Options, twice, and nothing found to disable it.

(actualy, it happens to all marching symbols like `"(<{`, so i guess it's something to do with the brace marching thing.)

Please help, thank you.

Comment: Do you use the ReSharper extension by any chance? It adds this feature and can be turned off in its options easily.

Comment: No， just the original vs2022.